# Selecting all friends from mysql database

Tags: mysql, select, join

I got a database with with users and their connection as friends.
I just want to request simply all friends of a user with their username and the status of their friendship where status can be 0 for pending or 1 for accepted.

The Tables are:

```
users          user_friend        friend
- id           - id               -id
- username     - friend_id
               - user_id
               - status
```

I just cant get the query right... Maybe someone can help me :)
What i want to get at the end is:
user_id username status

What i tried is: (even if its totally wrong x))

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, uf.friend_id, uf.status 
FROM friends f
INNER JOIN user_friend uf ON uf.user_id = :user_id AND uf.friend_id = f.id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = uf.user_id
```

Comment: Edit your question and put in the query that you have tried that isn't quite right.

Comment: Hey I added the query I've tried

Comment: I think i have to select all rows from "friend" where in "user_friend" user_id=myid and friend.id = user_friend.friend_id
And then after that select all users for these "friend" rows which are not me.. but i dont get any further and need help..

Comment: The table `friend` would seem to serve no purpose unless friends might not be users.

Answer (score 0):

First you can DROP table friends.

Then friends for a particular user (id = 1234):

```
SELECT
    CASE uf.user_id
        WHEN 1234 THEN u.username
        ELSE f.username END as friend_name,
    CASE uf.user_id
        WHEN 1234 THEN u.id
        ELSE f.id   END as friend_id,
    uf.status
FROM
    user_friends uf
JOIN
    users f
    ON uf.user_id = u.id AND uf.friend_id = 1234
JOIN
    users u
    ON uf.friend_id = f.id AND uf.user_id = 1234
```

Comment: I'll try and test it now! i know the table friends is kinda useless.. but how else should i manage then unique ids for friendships? Already a big thanks!

Comment: How do you manage know? The friends table doesn't add anything to ease managing that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data layout, you would seem to want something like this:

```
select f.*
from user u join
     userfriends uf
     on uf.user_id = u.id join
     friend f
     on uf.friend_id = f.id
where u.username = XXX;
```

Your data structure seems strange.  Normally, there would be no `friends` table.  Users would just befriend each other.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT u.UserId, f.FriendId, uf.Status
FROM Friend f
INNER JOIN UserFriend uf
ON f.FriendId = uf.FriendId
INNER JOIN Users u
ON uf.UserId = u.UserId WHERE u.UserId = '1'
```

This gets all UserId, FriendId and Status from a certain UserId.

Comment: OP's question was to get friends from a user, not friends from friends

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I clearly misread on the result he wanted. Updated my answer :)